# python "azure-storage-blob" package upload creates empty files

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I am using the "azure-storage-blob" package within fastAPI to upload a blob image to my Azure storage blob container. Aftera lot of trial and error I decided to just copy over a static file from my directory to the azure table storage. but everytime I upload the file it gets added as empty. If I write the file locally everything goes fine.

I am using the official documentation as decribed here:
https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/

I have the following code:

```
@app.post("/files/")
async def upload(incoming_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    fs = await incoming_file.read()
    file_size = len(fs)
    print(file_size)

    if math.ceil(file_size / 1024) > 64:
        raise HTTPException(400, detail="File must be smaller than 64kb.")

    if incoming_file.content_type not in ["image/png", "image/jpeg"]:
        raise HTTPException(400, detail="File type must either be JPEG or PNG.")

    try:
        blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=az_connection_string, container_name="app-store-logos",
                                                 blob_name="dockerLogo.png")

        with open("./dockerLogo.png", "rb") as data:
            blob.upload_blob(data)

    except Exception as err :
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file  {0}".format(err)}
    finally:
        await incoming_file.close()

    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {incoming_file.filename}"}
```

When I upload the file to the table storage the entry gets saved but empty:
[image]

If I change any filenames or storage names I do get an error, so the files exist and are in the right place, thoug it seems like the azure storage sdk doesnt copy over the contents of the file.

If anyone has any pointers I would be grateful

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. Can you check the size of `dockerLogo.png` file that you are trying to upload?

Comment: sure, the incoming size is 50112 bytes

Comment: If you notice in your code (`with open("./dockerLogo.png", "rb") as data:`), you are not uploading the incoming file. Rather, you are uploading `dockerLogo.png` file from local.

Comment: I was aware of that, though ur reply did push me in the right direction. The file turned out to be 0 bytes itself, which was a result of the file being read in the first few lines of code. The solution was to rewind the position of the file using:   await incoming_file.seek(0) 

thanks

Comment: Great. I have marked this question for closure. If you like, you can delete the question or post your solution as an answer.